# How can I make my SSIS process run faster?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

**EDIT**

***This question has been closed on SO and reposted on ServerFault***

https://serverfault.com/questions/333168/how-can-i-make-my-ssis-process-consume-more-resources-and-run-faster

I have a daily ETL process in SSIS that builds my warehouse so we can provide day-over-day reports.

I have two servers - one for SSIS and the other for the SQL Server Database.  The SSIS server (SSIS-Server01) is an 8CPU, 32GB RAM box.  The SQL Server database (DB-Server) is another8CPU, 32GB RAM box. Both are VMWare virtual machines.

In its oversimplified form, the SSIS reads 17 Million rows (about 9GB) from a single table on the DB-Server, unpivots them to 408M rows, does a few lookups and a ton of calculations, and then aggregates it back to about 8M rows that are written to a brand new table on the same DB-Server every time (this table will then be moved into a partition to provide day-over-day reports).

I have a loop that processes 18 months worth of data at a time - a grand total of 10 years of data. I chose 18 months based on my observation of RAM Usage on SSIS-Server - at 18 months it consumes 27GB of RAM. Any higher than that, and SSIS starts buffering to disk and the performance nosedives.

I am using [Microsoft's Balanced Data Distributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn912438(v=msdn.10)) to send data down 8 parallel paths to maximize resource usage. I do a union before starting work on my aggregations.

Here is the task manager graph from the SSIS server

[image]

Here is another graph showing the 8 individual CPUs

[image]

As you can see from these images, the memory usage slowly increases to about 27G as more and more rows are read and processed. However the CPU usage is constant around 40%.

The second graph shows that we are only using 4 (sometimes 5) CPUs out of 8.

I am trying to make the process run faster (it is only using 40% of the available CPU).

How do I go about making this process run more efficiently (least time, most resources)?

Comment: So I understand the process, data comes in from source (A) to the SSIS server (B), it's processed there and then goes to the destination server. Is Destination server C or does it go back to source server (A)?

Comment: @billinkc question edited to added content - source and destination are the same servers.

Comment: so its not CPU bound. Perhaps I/O bound?

Comment: @MitchWheat I read from a single source table with a single`WHERE` clause on the Date column. That column has a Clustered Index on it. I agree that it seems like it is I/O bound because of the slowness with which the data is brought in and processed.  How do I investigate where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: @closer: care to explain why SSIS programming is off topic?

Comment: Raj: So?. You haven't mentioned what your RAID setup and/or disk placement is. Disk is a finite resource....BTW, is anything else happening on the server at the time?  Try monitoring the perfmon diak counters...

Comment: @MitchWheat Both machines are on VMWare virtuals. I do not know what the RAID setup is. It is a brand new server with only my process running on it.

Comment: I believe this question belongs on serverfault.

Comment: "I have a loop..." is a Really Bad Thing™ to say when talking SQL

Comment: This is a programming question in my mind, at least until we eliminate the code as the limiting factor. @CAFxX Generally yes, loop + SQL means really bad things **unless** you're doing problems that require it. [Hugo Kornelis](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/tags/Bin+Packing/default.aspx) provides excellent hybrid approach (part iterative, part set based) for problem solving.

Comment: @CAFxX This is a data warehouse - tables are really wide (100+ columns). They won't give me a server big enough that will do all the calculations in memory. By my calculations, we will need 224GB of RAM to  process it all in one try. Plus we're looking at going 10 times the data size within the next 12 months. We will scale out instead of up (parallel processing on multiple servers), but at this point, I cannot get rid of the loop.

Comment: Disagree with closing this question, voted to reopen. SSIS is programming, this is a programming related website. OP wishes to improve performance of their SSIS package. It's a valid question and one we field with some regularity in this tag. Process improvement relates to programming or software development. It may not be the tool of choice for 2 of you closers but this is an on-topic question, the right tags and I would have enjoyed helping Raj More improve upon his design.

Comment: I am really sorry to see this question closed since in my opinion it belongs here and is very interesting. Why not moving to other stack site? Ray, please put link here if You post this same question somewhere else.

Comment: @FilipPopović posted on another site http://serverfault.com/questions/333168/how-can-i-make-my-ssis-process-consume-more-resources-and-run-faster

Comment: @billinkc posted on another site http://serverfault.com/questions/333168/how-can-i-make-my-ssis-process-consume-more-resources-and-run-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, all processing is bound by one of four factors

- Memory
- CPU
- Disk
- Network

The first step is to identify what the limiting factor is and then determine whether you can influence it (acquire more of or reduce usage of)

### Component choices

The reason your server's memory runs out when you do more than 18 months is related to why it takes so long for it to process. The [Pivot and Aggregate transformations](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) are asynchronous components. Every row coming in from the source component has N bytes of memory allocated to it. That same bucket of data visits all the transformations, has their operations applied and is emptied at the destination. That memory bucket is reused over and over again.

When an async component enters the arena, the pipeline is split. The bucket that was transporting that row of data must now be emptied into a new bucket to complete the pipeline. That copying of data between execution trees is an expensive operation in terms of execution time and memory (could double it). This also reduces the opportunity for the engine to parallelize some of the execution opportunities as it's waiting on the async operations to complete. A further slow down to operations is encountered from the nature of the transformations. The Aggregate is a fully blocking component so **all** the data has to arrive and be processed before the transformation will release a single row to the downstream transformations.

If it's possible, can you push the pivot and/or the aggregate onto the server? That should decrease the time spent in the data flow as well as the resources consumed.

You can try increasing the amount of parallel operations the engine can chose. [Jamie's article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/12/investigation-can-different-combinations-of-components-effect-dataflow-performance.aspx), [SQL CAT's article](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2010/08/18/increasing-throughput-of-pipelines-by-splitting-synchronous-transformations-into-multiple-tasks.aspx)

If you really want to know where your time is being spent in the data flow, log the OnPipelineRowsSent for an execution. Then you can use this [query](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesn/archive/2008/02/11/60504.aspx) to rip it apart (after substituting sysssislog for the sysdtslog90)

### Network transfer

Based on your graphs, it doesn't appear the CPU or Memory is taxed on either box. I believe you have indicated the source and destination server are on a single box but the SSIS package is hosted and processed on another box. You're paying a not-insignificant cost to transfer that data over the wire and back again. Is it possible to process the data on the source server? You'd need to allocate more resources to that box and I'm crossing my fingers that's a big beefy VM and that's not a problem.

If that's not an option, try settings the [Packet Size](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/top10lists/archive/2008/10/01/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices.aspx) property of the connection manager to 32767 and talk to network ops about whether jumbo frames are right for you. Both of those tips are in the Tune your Network section.

I suck at disk counters but you should be able to see if the wait types are disk related.

Answer (score 2):

Have you previously tried breaking the 18 months processing further into 2 or 3 more batches? unless of course your partitioning scheme will require all 18 months together in that partition --but then it would be come a curious matter to see how and why you're partitioning the data with that scheme. And it would still be okay to break into batches if you have validations in place when you recreate your indexes/constraints..

In my experience, I once had to create a job that would process between 50 and 60 million records and although the source was from data files and the destination was into a table in the server, breaking them into batches proved to be a faster method than going all out at once.

Are you worried about the nosedive performance because this is a highly-transactional database? If so, do you happen to have any data redundancy in place at your disposal?

[edit#01]

Re:Comment#01: Sorry if I'm quite confusing; I meant that on the scheduled day for processing the records, it would be good to have a scheduled job for your ssis package run at certain intervals (so test how long 1 month gets processed and take the average and give it a buffer for time) handling a month or two at a time (if possible) and then just set an additional task at the top to compute/determine which month is to be processed.

## Just an example:

< only assuming that two months take less than an hour to finish >

[scheduled run] : 01:00

[ssis task 01] get hour value of current time. if hour = 1 then set monthtoprocessstart = 1 and monthtoprocessend = 2

[ssis task 02 and so on] : work with data whose months are in the range (monthtoprocessstart and end for the year you are processing)

If this is more confusing just let me know so I can remove the edit.. Thanks..

Comment: I started with one month at a time and worked my way up to 18 months. This is a data warehouse being built after hours.